# Describe closures to a non programmer

Tags: closures

I will have a presentation about closures, and a non programmer friend of mine asked, what closures are. With what analogy would you describe that?
I mean "take a look at the lamba calculus" wouldn't be that nice.

Comment: Is this just out of curiosity or do you have a specific audience in mind? For someone with no programming background or interest I doubt there's any meaningful way to describe closures, or even ordinary functions and objects.

Comment: Partly out of curiosity,and when I was about to tell what my presentation is about to any friend, I couldn't make up any better then "you wouldn't understand".

Comment: Take a look at [How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6629/64132)

Comment: thanks @DanPichelman , yeah the problem is complex. I read a great analogy a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/2592349 and I was hoping for that kind of answer, but yeah, it's maybe not possible to have to this one.

Comment: `I will have a presentation about closures...` So you decided to delegate it to Programmers.SE?

Comment: @JimG. but does that mean, that I shouldn't be able to tell the very basics of closures to others? I don't think so.

Comment: I think you might first want to work on explaining just what a closure is to an audience of programmers.  Unless they're selected from the limited subset who do that sort of programming, of course.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there can be a misunderstanding. I do exactly know what I will say in my presentation, what I asked for is not related to that. That was only an analogy to closures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment I'm going to assume the target audience doesn't fully understand what a "function" is either, so here are my best attempts at defining "function" and "closure" to somebody *who has not ever written code of any sort*.

> A function is a piece of code that I can give some data, and it will
> give me back a result. For instance, I might have a function to compute
> the square root of a number.
>
> A closure is one way of making a function that can also "save" data
> and "remember" it later. For instance, I might have one closure to
> change an image's size, and another to check what the image's size
> currently is.

Comment: Now explain why you should do this, instead of having two functions/methods/subroutines, SetImageSize and GetImageSize.